# Trying to return 2 outputs with Plotly DASH

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly-dash

I'm trying to calculate the BMI and return both the BMI and the category it falls in, but it is only returning the BMI.

```
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("BMI Calculator"),
    html.Div([
        html.H2('Enter your weight'),
        dcc.Input(id = 'weight', value = 160, type = 'number'),
        dcc.RadioItems(options = [{'label': 'pounds', 'value': 'lbs'}, {'label': 'kilograms', 'value': 'kgs'}], 
                       value = 'lbs',
                       id = 'weight_unit'),
        html.H2('Enter your height'),
        dcc.Input(id = 'height', value = 5.83333333, type = 'number'),
        dcc.RadioItems(options = [{'label': 'feet', 'value': 'ft'},{'label': 'meters', 'value': 'm'}], 
                       value = 'ft', 
                       id = 'height_unit'),      
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.H1("Your estimated body mass index is:"),
    html.H1(id = 'bmi'),
    html.H1("BMI Classification:"),
    html.H1(id = 'bmi_class'),

])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id = 'bmi', component_property = 'children'),
    Output(component_id = 'bmi_class', component_property = 'children'),
    Input(component_id  = 'weight', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'weight_unit', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'height', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'height_unit', component_property = 'value'),
   )
    
def update_output_div(weight, weight_unit, height, height_unit):
    bmi = None 
    if weight_unit == 'lbs' and height_unit == 'ft':
        bmi = 703 * (weight/(height * 12)**2)
    if weight_unit == 'kgs' and height_unit == 'm':
        bmi = (weight)/((height)**2)
    return bmi 

def bmi_class(bmi):
    if bmi < 16:
        bmi_class = "Severe Thinness"
    elif bmi >= 16 and bmi < 17:
        bmi_class = "Moderate Thinness"
    elif rval >= 17 and rval < 18.5:
        bmi_class = "Mild Thinness"
    elif rval >= 18.5 and rval < 25:
        bmi_class = "Normal"
    elif rval >= 25 and rval < 30:
        bmi_class = "Overweight"
    elif rval >= 30 and rval < 35:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class I"
    elif rval >= 35 and rval < 40:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class II"
    elif rval >= 40:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class III"
    return bmi_class
```

**Error Message:**

```
dash._grouping.SchemaTypeValidationError: Schema: [<Output `bmi.children`>, <Output `bmi_class.children`>]
Path: ()
Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
Received value of type <class 'float'>:
22.955102067050735
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to merge both functions in one function as follows:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id = 'bmi', component_property = 'children'),
    Output(component_id = 'bmi_class', component_property = 'children'),
    Input(component_id  = 'weight', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'weight_unit', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'height', component_property = 'value'),
    Input(component_id  = 'height_unit', component_property = 'value'),
   )
    
def update_output_div(weight, weight_unit, height, height_unit):
    bmi = 0
    bmi_class = " "
    
    if weight_unit == 'lbs' and height_unit == 'ft':
        bmi = 703 * (weight/(height * 12)**2)
    if weight_unit == 'kgs' and height_unit == 'm':
        bmi = (weight)/((height)**2)
        
    
    if bmi < 16:
        bmi_class = "Severe Thinness"
    elif bmi >= 16 and bmi < 17:
        bmi_class = "Moderate Thinness"
    elif rval >= 17 and rval < 18.5:
        bmi_class = "Mild Thinness"
    elif rval >= 18.5 and rval < 25:
        bmi_class = "Normal"
    elif rval >= 25 and rval < 30:
        bmi_class = "Overweight"
    elif rval >= 30 and rval < 35:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class I"
    elif rval >= 35 and rval < 40:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class II"
    elif rval >= 40:
        bmi_class = "Obese Class III"
        
    return bmi , bmi_class
```

I initialized the `bmi` to `0` since it is an integer variable and `bmi_class` to `"  "`

**Output:**

[image]